# Linked API Error in Python - "Empty oauth2 access token" even though access token given

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, linkedin-api

I've been struggling with the following basic call to the linkedIn API.

I have received the 'OAuth 2.0 access token' through linkedIn's 'OAuth Token Tools' page and given it the proper scope (r_basicprofile) in order to complete the call. But when the call is made I get error
**{"serviceErrorCode":65604,"message":"Empty oauth2 access token","status":401}**
even though I have passed the token properly (see code below).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import requests
import json

access_token = 'Not displayed for obvious reasons'

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

me = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me',headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: Encountering the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The access token param you need to pass is `oauth2_access_token` not `access_token`.

For example:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token={linkedin_key}`

Comment: I edited my post to show that I am using the OAuth 2.0 access token. Still doesnt work

Comment: try that link: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token={access_token}`
Otherwise, you can go see the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-4-make-authenticated-requests

Comment: Thanks for sharing Marcucus. Your solution did not work. I now get error code 65600. In the docs it says that the format should be ```Authorization: Bearer (your access token)``` which is what the previous person did?